# Exclude bootstrap fonts while customization

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I remove all fonts family from bootstrap while build. Actually I want to use my custom fonts defined in `style.css`.

I have checked bootstrap website there is option for font change but not any for `font-family` removal.

Another solution is to override all fonts but I don't want to over-ride fonts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to override 'ALL' styles font from bootstrap but only certain element fonts, then just add a `!important` for that specific element font-family property.

Something like this:

```
#SpecialFontDiv    {
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial !important;
}
```

That way, you are not overriding the whole bootstrap.css font styles but just the elements you want.

Comment: i have mentioned in the question that I am not looking for an overriding solution.